# Connection problem while hosting multiple tor sites on same device

Tags: nginx, tor

I am trying to host two tor websites on the same device. The original one works but not the new one. I have followed the steps in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328007/how-to-set-up-multiple-tor-hidden-services-in-the-same-host) but I can't [connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmX63.png) to the server.

I've added a mew serviceDir and Port in /etc/tor/torrc

```
#this site works
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

#this one does not
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8081
```

and in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default I've added

```
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        listen [::]:8081 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

running nginx -t gives no error

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I am at a loss here. Any help is appreciated!